# Segfault while Implementing stack in C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, stack

I get a segfault while runnig this code to implement a stack in C. Please note that the code is kind of incomplete. I just wanted to check and see if I could push a few elements on to the stack and print them out. But it throws back a segfault. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct stack
{

int *elems;
int ll;
int al;
};

void stack_new(struct stack *s)

{
s->ll=0;
s->al=4;
s->elems=malloc(4*sizeof(int));
}

void stack_del(struct stack *s)
{
free(s->elems);
}

void stack_push(struct stack *s,int value)
{
if(s->ll==s->al)
{
printf("overflow");
/*s->al*=2;
s->elems=realloc(s->elems, s->al*sizeof(int));*/
}

s->elems[s->ll]=value;
s->ll++;
}

void stack_pop(struct stack *s)
{
s->ll--;
return (s->elems[s->ll]);
}

void main()
{
struct stack *s;

stack_new(s);
stack_push(s,3);
stack_push(s,4);
stack_push(s,8);

printf("%d", s->elems[0]);

//stack_pop(s);
//stack_del(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declaring

```
struct stack *s;
```

doesn’t allocate any memory for a `struct stack`. Do that:

```
struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
```

Or just put your stack on the stack:

```
struct stack s;

stack_new(&s);
…
```

Using more descriptive field names is also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors

1. You never initialize the pointer `s` in your `main` function, so in your `stack_new` function dereferencing `s` causes a segmentation fault.
2. You should allocate space for the stack first, wherever you want but you must.
3. Another thing is if you want to initialize your `al` field with a constant number and then allocate an array of constant size, you don't need the field `al`, and you can declare `elems` as `int elems[CONSTANT_NUMBER]` but if you want it to be dynamic, which is what I think you want from your check `if(s->ll == s->al)` in the `stack_push` function, then you can simply pass the value you want `al` to have to the `stack_new` function.

This is some of your code, fixed so you can see what I actually mean.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct stack
{
    int *elems;
    int  ll;
    int  al;
};

struct stack *stack_new(int al) /* you can pass the maximum number of elements allowed */
{
    struct stack *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;
    s->ll    = 0;
    s->al    = al;
    s->elems = malloc(al * sizeof(int)); /* and you dynamically allocate space for them here */

    return s;
}

void stack_del(struct stack *s)
{
    if (s != NULL) /* always check the pointers to prevent `SEGMENTATION FAULT` */
    {
        if (s->elems != NULL)
            free(s->elems);
        free(s);
    }
}

void stack_push(struct stack *s, int value)
{
    if (s == NULL)
        return;
    if(s->ll == s->al)
    {
        printf("overflow");
        /*s->al*=2;
        s->elems=realloc(s->elems, s->al*sizeof(int));*/
    }
    if (s->elems != NULL)
        s->elems[s->ll] = value;
    s->ll++;
}

int stack_pop(struct stack *s)
{
    if ((s == NULL) || (s->elems == NULL))
        return 0;
    s->ll--;
    return (s->elems[s->ll]);
}

int main()
{
    struct stack *s;

    s = stack_new(4);
    stack_push(s, 3);
    stack_push(s, 4);
    stack_push(s, 8);

    printf("%d", s->elems[0]);

    stack_pop(s);
    stack_del(s);

    return 0;
}
```

```